# Two nonempty sets that are bounded from above.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, supremum-and-infimum

It's given that: There is an $\epsilon>0$, such that for each $a\in$A, there is a $b\in$B such that $a+\epsilon < b$, Prove that $supA<supB$.

Note: Sup means supermum.

Here is what I did, and I hope you guys give me a Hint for how to continue from
here:

$SupA-\epsilon_1<a_1$ (which means that if we substract a little amount $\epsilon_1>0$ from $SupA$ there must be a member $a_1$ in  $A$ that is bigger than $SupA-\epsilon_1$.

By using the information they gave us, by substituting $a_1$, we get that there is an ($\epsilon>0$) such that $a_1+\epsilon<b_1$. (where $b_1$ is a certain member in $B$). and from this inequality w can deduce that $a_1<b_1$.

thus, we get that $SupA-\epsilon_1<b_1-\epsilon$

and I also know that $SupB+\epsilon>b_1$
so it means that:

- $SupA-\epsilon_1<b_1$
- $SupB>b_1-\epsilon$

but that inequality doesn't prove that $SupA<SupB$, what did I do wrong? and how do I continue from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here

$$\sup A-\epsilon_1<b_1-\epsilon,$$

try not to throw away that $\epsilon$. As $b_1\in B$, $b_1 \le \sup B$ and so

$$\sup A-\epsilon_1<\sup B-\epsilon. $$

Now this inequality holds for all $\epsilon_1 >0$. Thus we have

$$\sup A \le \sup B-\epsilon.$$

(Try to prove that by assuming the contrary that $>$ holds). Now as $\epsilon >0$, we have

$$\sup A \le \sup B-\epsilon < \sup B,$$

which is what you want.

**Remark** I hope this is clear that if you throw away that $\epsilon$ too early, you could at best get $\sup A \le \sup B$ (instead of the strict inequality $<$).

Comment: what if $\epsilon_1>\epsilon$? that third inequality won't be necessary right, because u are adding a positive value to $SupB$ and saying the sum is bigger than $SupA$, how do we know if $SupB>SupA$?

Comment: Recall how you choose $\epsilon_1$: it is any positive number. Not only can I choose $\epsilon_1<\epsilon $, I can even choose it to be as small as possible. @FirasAliAbdelGhani

Comment: great, you are right!, thanks a lot!